# Error 401 Invalid token in PostMan while trying to authenticate GET request

Tags: php, laravel, rest, postman, laravel-api

I'm trying to work with an API that already given me a TOKEN and I have added this TOKEN at `Authorization` section as **BearerToken** and then added this GET request (which requires no parameter):

`https://seller.digikala.com/api/v1/profile/`

But after sending it, I get the Status **`401 Unathorized`** somehow.

So what's going wrong here? How can I properly add this token and authenticate the request?

[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Ox0.png)

Comment: post a picture or a piece of code how you make a request in postman or laravel

Comment: @DaveRunner I just added it. Please see Screen Capture.

Comment: @nitinos are you sure token is valid?

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 I copy and paste the token. No chance for entering wrong token

Comment: You can double check the token with jwt.io. 401 means the authentication info is wrong.

Comment: Invalid Token implies as mentioned earlier a corrupt token value. You may use jwt.io or jwt.ms to check if the token is valid and shows the right set of entity details from it.